# What is the RxJS equivalent of Bacon.js bus?

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs, bacon.js

How can I create an Observable that I can just directly push events to, like with Bacon.js's Bus?

Comment: Please, try to avoid using Bus (and Subject in Rx). http://baconjs.blogspot.fi/2014/12/bus-of-doom.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The equivalent in RxJS is called Subject. It is both an Observer and an Observable. So to push events to it, you use it's Observer interface: the onNext, onError, and onCompleted methods. Then you can subscribe to it, map, zip, filter it like any Observable. Here's an example from the official docs:

```
var subject = new Rx.Subject();

var subscription = subject.subscribe(
    function (x) { console.log('onNext: ' + x); },
    function (e) { console.log('onError: ' + e.message); },
    function () { console.log('onCompleted'); });

subject.onNext(1);
// => onNext: 1

subject.onNext(2);
// => onNext: 2

subject.onCompleted();
// => onCompleted

subscription.dispose();
```

You can check the Subject getting started guide [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/subjects.md), and the Subject API docs [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/subject.md).

Comment: In RxJS v5, Subject's "onNext" method is now just "next", etc.